# Fetch some info and display it on login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use **Laravel 5** which has pre-setup the login page. I want to fetch some info from database such as `site_name` and display it on login page. But not sure how to configure it in file `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

and here is the default controller for `welcome`

```
<?php namespace ais\Http\Controllers;

class WelcomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $settings = Settings::findOrFail(1);
        return view('welcome', compact($settings));
    }

}
```

I add some code here to get the general settings for the page and set it in function `index()` like this `$settings = Settings::findOrFail(1);`

An error came out and say this to me

`Undefined variable: settings (View: /var/www/ais/resources/views/app.blade.php) (View: /var/www/ais/resources/views/app.blade.php)`

how do I display that information on login page?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass some variable into login page you need to create new function called "getLogin()" in  "/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php". And Then you can do whatever you want.

Example

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
public function getLogin()
{
  $someInfo = "Some Info" ;
  return view('auth.login', compact('someInfo'));
}
```

Then you can call  $someInfo inside "/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php"

Comment: that's very helpful. BTW where can I add this snippet for the registration and forgot password?

Comment: Yes, you do.  you might want to look for all the functions you want to overwrite from **"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php"** and **"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php"**.

Comment: I original function for **"registration"** was placed inside **"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegist‌​ersUsers.php"** with the function called **"getRegister()"** and **"forgot password"** was placed inside **"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php"** with function called **"getEmail()"**

Comment: is there any chance i do not want to touch any files under folder **vendor**

Comment: sorry for my explanation. you don't need to change any files inside vendor. But you need to look at the functions that you need from inside vendor and copy the functions to "app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php" or "/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php"

Answer (score 0):

For `compact` function you don't pass variable, you just pass variable name, so it should be:

```
return view('welcome', compact('settings'));
```

instead of

```
return view('welcome', compact($settings));
```

Comment: i see. but how do I pass it to `auth` view